# JDO exception after upgrading Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, nullpointerexception, upgrade, jdo

I have a simple(but very important for me) application in AppEngine. I use JDO.
I've upgraded to the latest version of App Engine, and have a strange jdo exception trying to access child entities.

Class Account
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "account")
    private ArrayList players = new ArrayList();

Class Player
    @Persistent
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private Account account;

It always worked OK. But after upgrading App Engine, every time I invoke myAccount.getPlayers() I get the following exception:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.getIndexPropertyName(FKListStore.java:965)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.getFilterPredicates(FKListStore.java:940)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.listIterator(FKListStore.java:383)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.listIterator(FKListStore.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.iterator(FKListStore.java:342)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList.loadFromStore(ArrayList.java:300)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:543)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could search for that stack trace, and find this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096928/javax-jdo-jdoexception-unexpected-error-during-precommit

Comment: same here, have you found the solution?