# GAE JDO NullPointerException on .add() operation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm trying to make a one-to-many relationship in GAE and when i'm adding to the list i'm getting the following error:

```
[java] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.getIndexPropertyName(FKListStore.java:965)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.getFilterPredicates(FKListStore.java:940)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.listIterator(FKListStore.java:383)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.listIterator(FKListStore.java:349)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.iterator(FKListStore.java:342)
 [java]     at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.List.loadFromStore(List.java:304)
 [java]     at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.List.add(List.java:685)
 [java]     at Utils.GardenUtils.PostMessage(GardenUtils.java:187)
 [java]     at Servlets.GardenServlets.PostGardenMessageServlet.processRequest(PostGardenMessageServlet.java:28)
 [java]     at Servlets.GardenServlets.PostGardenMessageServlet.doPost(PostGardenMessageServlet.java:70)
 [java]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 [java]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]     at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 [java]     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

This is how i'm adding the new list member:

```
    public static void PostMessage(String userID, String gardenKey, String content) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try {
        User user = pm.getObjectById(User.class, userID);

        GardenMessage message = new GardenMessage();
        message.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        message.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        message.setUserID(userID);
        message.setContent(content);
        message.setGardenKey(gardenKey);
        message.setPostDate(new Date());

        Garden garden = pm.getObjectById(Garden.class, gardenKey);
        garden.getMessages().add(message);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

On the Garden class I have this:

```
@Persistent
private List<GardenMessage> messages;
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that plugin of Google's had several updates after the last release (2.1.2), and they didn't bother releasing it. The code is at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk
The line where you have an NPE is definitely different from a cursory glance, so suggest you try their current SVN. You should be able to simply do a checkout and then "mvn clean install" to get a version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT (uses DataNucleus 3.2 IIRC).

A simple search also found this post [javax.jdo.JDOException: Unexpected error during precommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096928/javax-jdo-jdoexception-unexpected-error-during-precommit)